# New Israel Space station in Lagrangian point

Tags: story-identification, space, hard-sci-fi, post-apocalyptic

Back around 1986  I read a Sci Fi book that opens with a nuclear war in the middle east that destroyed Israel and surrounding countries.  The main part of the book dealt with life on a space station set up by the Jewish remnant located in one of the Lagrangian points.  There was strife between this Jewish space station and other Arab space stations (of course).  The space station was run by a self aware AI that chose to be Jewish because it made sense to 'it'.  In order to enter your home on the space station you had to put your thumb onto a scanner embedded in the upper right side of the door, i.e. on the Mezuzzah.  I can NOT remember the name or the author.  Anybody know it?

Comment: Try browsing through the [Jewish SF list](http://www.sfsite.com/~silverag/jewishsf.html) and see if any name rings a bell.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this might be Diasporah by W.R. Yates published in 1985.

> As the result of a Shite Final Solution, there are no longer any Israelis in the Middle East. the once-Fertile Crescent is a mass of radioactive slag. But unlike Islam, Israel survives. Sixty thousand miles beyond the Moon floats the space city HAZARA YSROEL. Begun 80 years before, it is now home to six million New Israelis, who for a while believed that they had found peace and prosperity beyond the confines of Earth. But the more things change the more they stay the same. Terrorist acts against HAZARA YSROEL are on the rise. The now-powerful United Nations makes pious noises - and does nothing. Soon the people of New Israel must make yet another powerful choice.

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671559745)

Comment: I just finished reading a copy of this and it definitely appears to match the description listed above by Moriel.  After I found it, it sounded like a good read and it was.  The ending was a bit predictable.  But I thought the character development (in particular the sentient AI which considered itself Jewish) was a very enjoyable.